# ES6 class setter is not recognized as a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, getter-setter

I'm trying to use getters and setters to adjust data initially set with a class constructor. The getter seems to work:

```
class myClass {
  constructor(sth) {
    this.data = {
      sth,
      timestamp: new Date()
    }
  }
  
  create(createData) {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, this.theData, {
    /*      this getter seems to work ^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
      createData
    })
    console.log(newData) // looks good
    // set'ter new data
    this.theData(newData)
    return this
  }
  
  get theData() {
    return this.data
  }
  
  set theData(newData) {
    console.log('setting')
    this.data = newData;
  }
}
         
const Instance = new myClass('construct data')
  .create({createData: 'some data'})
```

But this gets the error

> zakeyumidu.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: this.theData is not a function
>
> at myClass.create

creating a non-`setter` method seems to work as I can just do

```
setTheData(newData) {
  this.data = newData // yep, that works
}
```

But I get the idea that `getters`/`setters` are preferred.

#### Is it okay to set instance data like this within class methods like my example that works? If not, why is my setter not working?

Comment: is it compile time error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.theData(newData)` would be accessing `theData`'s *getter*. Since `.data` is not a function at the time that line executes (or ever), that is why you are getting that error.

To fix the problem, you should actually use the setter:

```
this.theData = newData;
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. This is preferred to directly setting the `this.data` value? Do you know why?

Comment: @1252748 That's a matter of opinion. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors) for some discussion of the merits and demerits of using getters and setters.

Comment: Wow, took me an hour to find your valuable answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `this.theData(newData)` you should write `this.theData = newData`

```js
class myClass {
  constructor(sth) {
    this.data = {
      sth,
      timestamp: new Date()
    }
  }

  create(createData) {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, this.theData, {
    /*      this getter seems to work ^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
      createData
    })
    console.log(newData) // looks good
    // set'ter new data
    this.theData = newData;
    return this
  }

  get theData() {
    return this.data
  }

  set theData(newData) {
    console.log('setting')
    this.data = newData;
  }
}

const Instance = new myClass('construct data')
  .create({createData: 'some data'})
```